# Plot multiple variables and regression test using Pandas and using Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, frame

actually, I have a data frame, first, I delete all the rows whose have non_value data using

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'file path', usecols= 'B:L')
df1 = df.dropna()
```

> i want to see the correleation between all the variables 'columns'and regression line in my data using pairplot

```
plt.show()
df1.corr(method='spearman')
```

it works but only with the last two variables in my data frame, I don't know why
help me, please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll have to include your data/sample data and the current output you are getting so that people here can help you

Comment: As @sai said, it's hard to help without the data, but it could be because some of your columns are string (object) so `pairplot` and `corr` doesn't plot/compute values for those columns.